# Why does Cherevin try to have Ryan killed when he doesn't need to?

Tags: plot-explanation, jack-ryan-shadow-recruit

In Jack Ryan: Shadow Recruit, Ryan's character is acting as a banking compliance officer and is sent to Moscow to review and audit some secret accounts in Cherevin's organisation (and in the hope that this will uncover more than just banking malfeasance).

When Ryan arrives in Moscow, his bodyguard tries to kill him as soon as he arrives at his hotel. The bodyguard is working for Cherevin.

The next day, when Ryan meets Cherevin and requests access to the accounts, they have all been offloaded by Cherevin's organisation so can no longer be audited. This stops Ryan in his tracks and effectively neutralises the threat.

So what was the point of trying to kill him?

Answer (score 3):

To play it safe.

Given that he planned far *"more than just banking malfeasance"*, there was a chance *Jack Ryan* was not just your average finance analyst (*Cherevin* might even have known already that *Ryan* worked for the CIA) and that he might still keep digging further, even if his "official" enquiry was put to an end. And in fact that's exactly what he did, the offloading of the accounts did certainly *not* stop *Ryan* threatening the operation.

All that counted for *Cherevin* was that the operation, scheduled in a few days, was successful and in this case a dead fincance analyst was better than risking any open ends, no matter if he belonged to the CIA or not (and even more so if he did). Even if this meant risking a bigger investigation following after his death. *Ryan there and then* was a potentially bigger threat than a possible investigation for his death *later on*. If he was just an ordinary finance analyst, then nobody cares about his death anyway, and if he wasn't, then he is too big a threat for the operation to be let alive.

But I admit that this is entirely speculation and this part might have as well been a little plot inconsistency.